# link with correct href still gives 404

Tags: html

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out why a link in one of my sites is broken. It gives a 404 even though the href is correct and the page exists.

The site is:
http://www.theawesomecleaners.com/

and the link is the big beige lettering "DFW areas" just below the menu. Here's the exact code for it:

```
  <h2>Serving <a href="http://www.theawesomecleaners.com/dfw-cleaners‎">DFW areas</a> 24/7 year around</h2>
```

After you see the 404, then visit the page from the url bar or search "our location" in the site, and you'll find the page right there.

What could be the problem?! I've tried excluding "www", adding "/ at the end, and using a relative path. None of them worked. I am really stumped. Please help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not giving you a 404 error. The page gives `200 OK` (which means "found") and whatever is, I presume, dynamically generating the page is writing "404 Error" in its content somewhere.

Comment: I am pretty sure I am getting a 404? That is what is says on my screen...

Comment: Linux, win? outline your setup and people can more readily help. Show us your .htaccess file if you have one - it may tell us what's happening here.

Comment: It may say `404 File Not Found` in the webpage itself but that is not the same as receiving a 404 error from the webserver. Go to http://web-sniffer.net/ and enter your link href there. You will see the Status is `200 OK`.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to an encoding error. It's a invisible character that is on the end of your url within the code that is creating the "%E2%80%8E" to appear.

Ensure that "http://www.theawesomecleaners.com/dfw-cleaners" is pasted into your html from some plain text location, such as this very post.

This happens when using things such as MS Word or WordPad.

Comment: Curiously, `%E%80%8E` is the %-encoded form of U+200E LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK, so a copy and paste operation has somehow picked it from some data (or inserted it).

Answer (score 2):

**With click:**

[image]

**With Search:**

[image]

Try to write the link manually, don't copy it from the MS Word or WordPad.